# How to round value in Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteria-api

Is it possible to round value in criteria api

For example I have double value a = 4.43444;

I want to make it 4.4 in criteria api.

this value goes from the calculating:

```
cb.quot(cb.sum(
                cb.avg(toBigDecimalProductReviewRating(cb, joinProductReview)),
                cb.avg(joinProductDefaultRating.get(ProductDefaultRating_.DEFAULT_AVG_RATING))), 2)
```

Comment: Where does the value comes from? From the db?

Comment: It's calculated from the values that goes from db

Comment: There is no round function in JPQL or Criteria API. Does your database have a round function?

Comment: Are u talking about custom function or function in native sql ?
Cause we are using postgres that's why there is a random function in postgres

Comment: Then you should read this guide: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL:

```
cb.function("round", Number.class, expression);
```

works well.

For 2 decimal digits:

```
cb.function("round", Number.class, expression, 2);
```